# Mouse scrolling, flash and wmode=transparent (windows)

Tags: flash, google-chrome

Got problem on Windows with mouse scrolling on flash object. 
Here is the site: http://wojciechkoszyk.pl/panoramy/20120307-oklesna_most/index.html

This is a virtual tour as a flash object and ON that, with position: absolute is a map from Google. I use wmode=transparent to show the object (Google map) on flash.

On Mac OS X everything works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. 
On Windows in Chrome and Firefox mouse scrolling doesn't work on flash object (scrolling is used to zooming the panorama). When I put panorama to fullscreen (button in right top corner) scroll works fine.

And, to be honest, I have no idea how to repair it.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of bugs/issues related to `mousewheel` of embedded flash.One of them -> http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-23724

It is commonly occuring problem. But also there is a [solution](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=13086).